# How to colour particles (in particle settings) based on vertex colour of emitter object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, vertex-colors

In Blender 2.8, cycles renderer.

I'm using an imported .ply object (which includes vertex colours) to generate a single particle on each vertex of the object. The idea is to create a point cloud effect.

How would I setup my nodes to use the emitter .ply object's vertex colours as the colours for the generated particles?

Is this even possible?

Blender n00b so, assume no knowledge :)

Many Thanks

Mike